# How to give categories to array data in a class, which would be displayed in various table view according to categories?

Tags: arrays, swift, class, categories

I am new to the programming field. I want to make an app, which should categorize array data within a class and display them in various table view as per the tab bar.

For example: I want to prepare a swift training courses in table view via tab bar.

Categories: Popular, Level, duration, etc.

How should I create a data array and categorize them in a class? So whenever I call that array in various table views, I can filter them and dont need to re-type the same data on various array as per the categories.

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary will be better alternative than an Array. Set the different categories as the keys in the dictionary. And the values can be stored in an array.

```
        let theDictionary = [
        "Popular":["Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"],
        "Level":["Basic","Intermeidate","....."],
        "Duration":["Short","Long"]]
```

To populate this in a table view, you will extract each of the key value paris. The Rows of the table will the contents of the Array object.

Comment: Thanks for the response, have managed to populate data via custom classes using arrays but will need to try dictionary.